# How to get a button from a Google Apps dialog

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-apps-script

I must be missing something really stupid here, but I just cannot work to get an interface button from a dialog box in Google Apps.

If I try to set the `disabled` to false in a `this` object from the "click" function, the button is enabled. But if I try `$('#dialog-ok-button').disabled = false;` it does just nothing!!!:

Code (I'm aware there are repeated actions in the code, it's an example comparing what I tried!):

```
...
<button class="action" id="dialog-ok-button" >OK</button>
...

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

$(function() {
  $('#dialog-ok-button').click(onExecuteClick);    
});


function onExecuteClick() {
   this.disabled = true; //disables the button

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(
      function(msg, element) {
        showStatus('Execution successful.');

//---------HERE---------

        element.disabled = false; //this works!
        $('#dialog-ok-button').disabled = false; //this NEVER works!

//---------HERE---------
      })
    .withFailureHandler(....)
    .withUserObject(this)
    .doSomething();

function showStatus(msg, classId) {

//-------HERE TOO---------
  $('#dialog-ok-button').disabled = false; //this NEVER works!
  $('#script-status').removeClass().html(msg); //this works!
//-------HERE TOO---------
  if (classId) {
    $('#script-status').addClass(classId); //this works!
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery selector you need to enable it using `prop`

```
$('#dialog-ok-button').prop('disabled',false); //Or true to disable it
```

Comment: Great! I knew it was some newbie thing

Comment: By the way, what should I refer to when trying to learn about this `$('#...').` way of coding? What's the name of it?

Comment: @Daniel Those are jquery [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).